# Dirac field local observables

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, commutator, causality

This is actually a continuation of calculation I've been working on. It is well known that, in the case of Dirac fields $\psi(x)$, they satisfy anticommutatation relationships since they're fermionic fields (in constrast to bosons, which satisfy commutation relationships). The general anticommutator is:

$$\{\psi_a(x),\bar{\psi_b}(y)\}=(i\partial_{slash}+m)_{\alpha\beta}(D(x-y)-D(y-x))$$

Where $D(x-y)$ is the usual propagator for free particle and $\bar{\psi}=\psi\gamma_0$.

In particular, for spacelike intervals $(x-y)^2<0$, $D(x-y)$ is an even function of $(x-y)$ so the above commutator becomes zero in this interval.

According to several articles (i.e. http://bolvan.ph.utexas.edu/~vadim/classes/16f/diprop.pdf), if the Dirac fields satisfy either anticommutation or commutation relationships, their local observables, which can be defined as the bilinear $O(x)=\bar{\psi_a}(x)O_{ab}(x)\psi_b(x)$, must commute outside the light cone. In other words, since the above relationship holds for spacelike intervals, the commutator:

$$[O(x),O(y)]=0 \ \ \ \ \ , \ \ \ \ for  \ \ \ \ \ (x-y)^2<0.$$

However, I was wondering if there's a direct way to prove this statement, as all the books (i.e. Weinberg) and articles I've found such state this fact, which seems logical but yet no proof is offered. I tried working directly the commutator:

$$[O(x),O(y)]=[\bar{\psi_a}(x)O_{ab}(x)\psi_b(x),\bar{\psi_a}(y)O_{ab}(y)\psi_b(y)].$$

By introducing the definitions and developing the integrals, but I cannot find a way to derive the result. Moreover, I'm pretty sure that there should be a way to use the above commutator for a more simple proof.

Comment: Never mind, I just found in Greiner "Field Quantization" the solution to this one. I will post it later so it remains available for others.

Comment: Quantum Field Theory by Mandl also covers the question, although you have to put up with the very old-fashioned notation.